# Error on installing momentjs using bower

Tags: bower, momentjs

I'm trying to install [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) using bower:

```
bower install -S momentjs
```

But I get the following error:

```
bower ngStorage#0.3.0       not-cached git://github.com/agrublev/ngStorage.git#0.3.0
bower ngStorage#0.3.0          resolve git://github.com/agrublev/ngStorage.git#0.3.0
bower momentjs#2.6.0            cached git://github.com/moment/moment.git#2.6.0
bower momentjs#2.6.0          validate 2.6.0 against git://github.com/moment/moment.git#2.6.0
bower momentjs#*                cached git://github.com/moment/moment.git#2.6.0
bower momentjs#*              validate 2.6.0 against git://github.com/moment/moment.git#*
bower ngStorage#0.3.0     ENORESTARGET No tag found that was able to satisfy 0.3.0

Additional error details:
Available versions: 0.1.7, 0.1.6, 0.1.5
```

It looks like there's some sort of mix up between different repositories named ngStorage.

```
bower search ngStorage
```

Gives:

```
Search results:

    ngstorage git://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage.git
    ngStorage git://github.com/agrublev/ngStorage.git
```

The #0.3.0 tag exists for gsklee/ngStorage, but not for agrublev/ngStorage. (I already have the gsklee package installed for my project.)

How can I can workaround or fix whatever it is that is giving the error when trying to install momentjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by:

1) Removing the following line from bower.json:

```
"ngStorage": "0.3.0"
```

2) Installing momentjs using:

```
bower install -S momentjs
```

3) Reinstalling ngstorage using:

```
bower install -S ngstorage
```

I suspect the issue was that I had manually edited bower.json (hadn't used -S while installing) and had the wrong entry for the ngstorage dependency (it was nsStorage, but should have been ngstorage - case sensitive)